# How can I modify a provider when receiving data from AsyncValueWidget

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I tried modifying a provider in the AsyncValueWidget and got the error '*Tried to modify a provider while the widget tree was building.*' How can I fix it?

**My code:**

```
AsyncValueWidget(
              value: ref.watch(planCategoriesProvider),
              data: (data) {
                selectedPlansNotifier.state = data
                    .expand((e) => e.plans)
                    .toList()
                    .where((e) => profile.plans.map((e) => e.id).contains(e.id))
                    .toList();
                return widget;})
```

Comment: You could move the update into a post frame callback.

Answer (score 0):

looks like pgs commend you can try the update to code after building the entire widget
So that use  addPostFrameCallback which is run after rebuilding the widget

```
     AsyncValueWidget(
          value: ref.watch(planCategoriesProvider),
          data: (data) {
       WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
         (_) {
          selectedPlansNotifier.state = data
                .expand((e) => e.plans)
                .toList()
                .where((e) => profile.plans.map((e) 
                 e.id).contains(e.id))
                 .toList();
            },);
            
             return widget;})
```